# How to fetch complex json into React Native Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, api

I'm trying to fetch an API from [a news API](https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=my&category=sports&apiKey=73e8cdd9f6be475cb4a2d128bae3650c) however the format is a little hard for me to extract the data from. I have tried to parse the json into an array but still wasn't able to fetch the data into a flatlist. May I have any suggestion to overcome this problem? thanks for any help. I've built this on expo which can be tested on the following [link](https://snack.expo.dev/@fahmijaafar/api-example).
The following is the API class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, ActivityIndicator, FlatList} from 'react-native';

export default class API extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: null
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=my&category=sports&apiKey=73e8cdd9f6be475cb4a2d128bae3650c')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      //tried to simplify the json(I'm not sure whether its right)
      //var parsedjson = JSON.parse(responseJson);
      //var myarray = parsedjson.articles;
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: responseJson//myarray,
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  _renderItem = ({item, index}) =>{
    return(
        //I think here's the problem. I've tried to use {item.articles.title}
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    )
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
            <ActivityIndicator style={{marginTop: 250}} size="large" color='white'/>
      )
    }else{

      let {data, isLoading} = this.state;
      return(
          <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item,index)=> index.toString()}
          />
    )
    }
  }
}
```

Using the same way, I managed to fetch API which has a format like

```
[
   {
       "id": "1",
       "title": "GG",
       "body": "the body here",
       "image": "image link",
       "link": null
   }]
```

but now its not working when using json with format like this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 38,
  "articles": [
     {
       "source": {
         "id": "the-washington-post",
         "name": "The Washington Post"
       },
       "author": "Rachel Lerman, Cat Zakrzewski, Heather Kelly",
       "title": "Apple"
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `componentDidMount`, you have

```js
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=my&category=sports&apiKey=73e8cdd9f6be475cb4a2d128bae3650c')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

      //var parsedjson = JSON.parse(responseJson); 
      // you don't need to parse the json here. It's already a JSON object.
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: responseJson, // here you can do either responseJson or responseJson.articles.
      })

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

You don't need to use `JSON.parse()` on a JSON. You can read more about JSON parse at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Now, in your `FlatList`, you have,

```js
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item,index)=> index.toString()}
/>
```

In your `data` prop of `Flatlist`, change the data to either `data.articles` or just `data` depending on the state you have set to your data.

If you have used,

```js
this.setState({
  isLoading: false,
  data: responseJson,
})
```

You will have to make the data prop of FlatList like below,

```js
<FlatList
  data={data.articles}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item,index)=> index.toString()}
/>
```

Or if you have set the data state as,

```js
this.setState({
  isLoading: false,
  data: responseJson.articles,
})
```

you can simply keep the `FlatList` as it is now.

Now on your _renderItem,

```js
_renderItem = ({item, index}) =>{
    return(
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    )
  }
```

This is how it should be. You don't need to use `{item.articles.title}`, as you have already supplied the `articles` array to your `FlatList` component.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Now I understand that by setting the value of data variable with responseJson.articles will enable me to use the API as I've always used before.

Comment: Cool. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

what you want to fetch from the given json, if u have multiple date in json then you have to pass positions.
you have to write like this
import jsonObject from 'path'
then if u want to get articles array then write
jsonObject.articles etc

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.